# PayPal Recurring Payment - Disallow Cancelling Profile

Tags: paypal-subscriptions

Is it possible in PayPal Standard to not allow a buyer to cancel a preapproved recurring payment?

Answer (score 0):

To cancel a subscription is logical right for both seller and buyer. Buy can always cancel a pre-approved recurring payment if he/she want. Seller of course can terminate the recurring service if buyer cancel it.